# How to put facebook's facepile on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facepile

I am currently trying to put a facepile that looks just like the one on this site:
http://www.studentdebtrelief.us/forgiveness/obama-student-loan-forgiveness/

When I go on the code generator on facebook, it only comes out with a facepile that doesn't have a like button or a company logo or any kind of structure to it really. The one the code generator makes looks just like a few faces put together. I don't facebook API very well so I am sure I am doing it wrong. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: [facepile was abandoned](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/)

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Facepile, it is a Like Box: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages

Facepiles can be used for Apps, Like Boxes are for Pages.